# Picasso load images from database android

Tags: android, picasso

Here is the problem, picasso by default can load Image Uri, File, drawable or string path. In my code below I have my adapter set like this:

```
public class RecyclerDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        public ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray;
        private Context context;
        private Bitmap bmp;

public RecyclerDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bm) {
            this.bitmapArray = bm;
            this.context = context;
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(bitmapArray.get(i)).resize(240, 120).into(viewHolder.img_android);
}

}
```

I am calling my adapter like this:

```
RecyclerDataAdapter adapter = new RecyclerDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),bitmapArray);
recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Basically my bitmap array has images from database

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ImageByte, 0, ImageByte.length, options);
bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
```

So could anyone tell me how to add images from bitmap array to .load in picasso. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need picasso if you've already decoded the bitmaps. Although, it would be better to have images on disk and only string paths in database and adapter. Then you could let picasso load images from disk and manage memory on bind as you intended.

Comment: Initially I had gridview to show images, but it does not display them correctly in a grid. That's the reason tried picasso for better image display